# Why do earthworms have so little colour?

Tags: pigmentation, annelida

Earthworms (or at least the ones that I have seen) tend to be pinkish, but with the front dorsal region being a camoflagued brown. Why is this the case, rather than the entire body or back being pigmented. I couldn't find any reference to the reasons behind earthworm colouration
[image: An image from wikipedia, showing the concentrated pigmentation]
Here is a picture from the wikipedia page on earthworms, showing the concentrated pigmentation

Comment: If they spend most of their time under the ground where nothing can see them, then what use is pigmentation?

Comment: @jamesqf But when it is raining they move to the surface where they are visible. And rains are not that rare. And besides that, why pink, of course?

Comment: @rus9384: Re "rains are not that rare", that depends on where you live, but even in a rainy place, the time spent above ground (and during the day) is a very small fraction of an earthworm's life, thus any color selection pressure would be small. (Besides, a lot of dirt IS more-or-less earthworm color :-))  As for pink, flesh is generally pinkish, especially if your blood contains hemoglobin, as that of earthworms does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthworm#Circulatory_system

Comment: @jamesqf But why would the pigment of an earthworm be so concentrated on the back, rather than more spread out?

Comment: @Ichthys King: Is it?  I am no expert on earthworms, beyond those I run across while gardening &c, but they seem fairly uniformly colored to me.

Comment: @jamesqf I have definitely seen earthworms with completely brown backs and pale pink bellies and rear-ends

Answer (score 1):

The reason appears to be the [light cells of Hess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthworm#Photosensitivity), which are light-sensitive cells distributed over the back of earthworms, being more concentrated towards the head

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question which is "Why?" i.e. for what (adaptive) reason. The light cells of Hess are not a reason so much as a small part of a mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

When creatures live in caves and darkness, they have negative selection against skin color, so they develop albinism.

[Here's a quote:](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6169799)
Epidermis pigmentation normally protects organisms from the harmful effects of UV irradiation, reduces the extent of predation through camouflage and mimicry, and facilitates sexual reproduction by mediating colorful behavioral displays (Protas and Patel 2008).

Healthy soil has easily 100-200 worms per square meter of soil, (as many as 1000 even), and we only see 1% of that, so it suggests they spend nearly all the time underground.

When it rains they migrate some distance.